# Track which user performed an api POST from web app client

Tags: rest, api, web-applications

So I'm designing a REST API for a web app that I am building. In the future the API will also be public, not just consumed by the app's client.

When a POST is made to some resources, I want to know which user performed that action, because editing that resource in the future will be restricted to the user that created it. This is simple enough for a public API, where each user has their own auth token.

For the purposes of the web app, however, I was thinking my client would just have its own token to consume the API. What is the best way to have the current logged in user id included in a request coming from the client?

Thoughts I had

- Send the current user id as a custom header in the request. Probably the simplest solution I've thought of.
- Send the current user id as a body property. This is just as simple but I don't like the idea of the web app sending a different request body than a public API consumer would.
- Have a different token for my client for every logged in user. This seems overly complicated and not worth the effort.
- API sessions. I don't know much about this and again, it seems like more work than necessary.

What might be the best solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After thinking through the problem more, and asking around in person, I think it makes the most sense for the API communication between the 1st party client and the 3rd party API consumer to be exactly the same.

Therefore the client would have to receive a user token on login, along with user information, to use for actions on behalf of the user.

Another benefit that has been pointed out to me is that there is less chance of a security threat by avoiding a single point of access for the client.